# how to change file extension of a config file (c#)

Tags: c#

First, ConfigureManager is what I want, but it always uses .config as file extension. Can I change .config to other string?

Comment: are you referring to your_appname.exe.config?

Answer (score 3):

Like @Dave, I'm assuming you mean the app configuration file. In which case "not easily". You *can* do it, but it involves spawning a second `AppDomain` with a bespoke `AppDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile`. To be honest, I don't think it is worth the effort, but the following works (prints `"bar"` the second time) - but first a warning: this will be a pain, especially getting things like resolution paths, evidence, etc straight. I really wouldn't bother...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["foo"]);
        if (!args.Contains("run"))
        {
            AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
            setup.ConfigurationFile = "foo.xml";
            AppDomain dmn = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Foo", null, setup);
            dmn.ExecuteAssembly(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase,
               new string[] { "run" } /* crude exit condition */
            );
        }
    }
}
```

with config file `foo.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="foo" value="bar"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create an almost empty configuration file with a custom section. Then use the configSource attribute of your custom section to specify a external configuration file. This external file can have any extension you want.

Extract from the .exe.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="mappings" type="MappingsSection, [AssemblyName]"/>
  <configSections>
  <mappings configSource="Mappings.conf" />
```

Extract from mappings.conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mappings>
 ...
</mappings>
```

To create a custom section, you can use [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)